# Constraint solver vs Bayesian optimizer for fast discontinuous processes

Tags: optimization, constrained-optimization

I have a complex domain-specific process that accepts **inputs**:

- 10-500 inputs, where each input is of type:

  - enum: choice between multiple string or numeric values
  - int: integers
  - float: floating point numbers
  - boolean: can be considered a enum(0,1)

It outputs several dozen outputs that I have clubbed together with weights to form an **output singular composite loss function**.

The process:

- Is non-linear with an unknown polynomial degree
- Is discontinuous
- Can be evaluated quickly in parallel (<10 s per evaluation)

The third point above seems to make pure Bayesian Optimization a suboptimal choice for this problem, as per [skopt](https://scikit-optimize.github.io/notebooks/bayesian-optimization.html):

> If you do not have these constraints *[f is expensive to evaluate]*, then there is certainly a better optimization algorithm than Bayesian optimization.

Should I be looking at constraint solvers, instead, since the inputs are well defined (if discontinuous)?

What is the difference between a constraint solver and a Bayesian optimizer in this case?

---

Details:

The real-world process is actually extremely time-consuming, but I have generated a decision-tree Regression model that evaluates predictions rather quickly.

Comment: Could you clarify: Are you saying that being able to evaluate quickly in parallel makes this a bad fit for blackbox optimization? It seems to me that it would still work, but that you'd want a batched optimizer to take advantage of the parallelism.

Comment: I'm following the advice here: https://scikit-optimize.github.io/notebooks/bayesian-optimization.html

Namely the disclaimer: "If you do not have these constraints [f is expensive to evaluate], then there is certainly a better optimization algorithm than Bayesian optimization."